# Acts_as_tenant, cached data for different tenants?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-tenant

I made a user with two accounts, a user should have documents that are scoped to the account they belong to.  I'm writing tests that @user.documents should be different if they are under `@account_1` vs `@account_2`

```
ActsAsTenant.with_tenant(@account_1) do
  @account_1_documents = @user.documents
end

ActsAsTenant.with_tenant(@account_2) do
  @account_2_documents = @user.reload.documents
end

expect(@account_1_documents).not_to eq @account_2_documents
```

Unfortunately this fails, maybe because it is cached?  If I do it in console and set the current tenant, I get back different documents.

Answer (score 0):

I think my intuition was right, `@user.documents` is cached, and you can't count on `@user.reload` or `@user.documents.reload` to get the current object, you have to call `reload` on both at the same time.

So doing `@user.reload.documents.reload` ended up working and making the tests pass.